# How do I set a profile directory when launching firefox?

Tags: linux, firefox, firefox-profile

I have a system which has Firefox installed in `/usr/bin/firefox` that uses profiles in `~/.mozilla/firefox`.

I have installed a new additional `firefox` in `/opt/myapplication`. I would like for the new firefox to look for and store profiles in `~/.myapplication`. Additionally, when attempting to launch `/opt/myapplication`, if no profiles exist in `~/.myapplication`, a new profile should be automatically created. ie. a new system user should not need to create a profile before launching the `/opt/myapplication` version of FireFox, and neither version should be aware of the others existence.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: While you can control where individual profiles are stored on your computer, AFAIK there's no way to change the location of the `profiles.ini` file itself which is where the path to each one is stored (in your case is `~/.mozilla/firefox`). You probably could effectively move it with a symbolic link, but you'd need to play games to get that set to the desired value before launching the different versions you have installed. It might be easier to just have them all share the `profile.ini` and just use profiles with different unique names.

Comment: It looks like I might be able to set `MOZ_APP_PROFILE` in `browser/confvars.sh` and compile a version that points to a different path. I haven't been able to find any documentation on the format of `MOZ_APP_PROFILE` though.

Comment: Looks like you can get it to ignore the `profiles.ini` altogether by using the [`-profile`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Command_Line_Options#-profile_.22.2Fpath.2Fto.2Fprofile.22) command-line option.

Comment: I saw that, but I'd really like for it to automake the whole directory and a default profile if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Rather than recompile it, it looks like you could add a [`Profile=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_Application_Packaging) option in the `[App]` section of each version's `application.ini` file which is stored in the executable program's folder.